# Dont understand why new android projects are automatically syntax error?

Tags: android

When I create a new android project (following these steps: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html) I automatically get syntax errors and I don't get it. I have attached a photo of the problem. Please help. I downloaded everything I needed to and in the older versions of this, everything worked fine.

[image: http://imgur.com/istF4 <-- the photo of what show up on my monitor]

Comment: it hasn't loaded all the resources yet, so it doesn't know what you're talking about

Comment: Try going to `Project -> Clean` a couple of times.

Comment: @K-ballo's answer is correct. I thought you meant on startup, because it does that to any project on startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are importing the wrong `R`. You should be doing

```
import com.chatnexttofriends.R;
```

instead of

```
import com.android.R;
```

This could have happened if you used the *Organize Imports* option before the automatically generated files where created, or because there was an error in your resources that prevented the automatically generated files from being created.

If you intend to use resources from both `R`s, then you will have to *fully qualify* one of them. I would suggest qualifying *Android's R*. *I.e.*:

```
setContentView(android.R.layout.activity_list_item);
```

Although I doubt you want to set the content of your `Activity` to that of an item representing an `Activity` in a `ListView`.